# Checking sheet existance using vba code and then run my macro within sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I' am looking for a code to check Sheet names initially like A, B, C. If sheet A exist then it should run the code which is goto A1: else it should go to B and check if Sheet B exist, if sheet B exist then it should run code below B1, Same way for sheet C as well.

Ex:
For I = 1 to worksheets.count
If Sheets(i).Name = "A" Then
GoTo A1
Else
GoTo B
End If
Next I

I have tried all the codes which are in this site related to worksheets.

Comment: i have already checked those answers, they arent working

Comment: Please see [ask] and [reprex].